# Split changes affecting certain files into different branch

Tags: git

Say I've been working on files a, b, c and d in a single branch. Now I realise I'd prefer to have my changes to a and b in one branch, and my changes to c and d in another, so from each branch's perspective it's as though I've only ever modified two files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The index is the tool git uses to handle this kind of need.

All your changes are detected by git but not "staged" (as in, ready for commit) until you say so.

```
# in case you already added all or part of your changes, undo it
git reset

# if needed, create the new branch (or stay on the one you worked on from start)
git checkout -b new_branch

# now add only parts for branch 1
git add a b
git commit -m "Modified a and b"
# let's call this commit Y

# now for the second part
git checkout -b new_branch_2 master
git add c d
git commit -m "Modified c and d"
# let's say this commit Z
```

resulting in this situation *(I assume here your base branch before all this was called* `master`, *whose last commit is* `X`*)*

```
     Y <<< new_branch_1
    /
---X <<< master
    \
     Z <<< new_branch_2 <<< HEAD
```

Finally, to be very explicit, now your files `a` and `b` are indeed unchanged (from `master`) in `Z`.